# How to describe these movements?

Tags: word-choice

If one takes this head-rope and pulls it back and forth, one can control the movement of all the threads of the net, and the whole net will be unfolded or collected accordingly.

I do not know how to describe the openning and closing of this fish net. It is made up of a head-rope. Can I use "unfold" and "collect"?

Answer (score 1):

'> If one takes this head-rope and pull it back and forth, one can control the

> movement of all the threads of the net, and the whole net will be unfolded or 
>   collected accordingly.
>
> I do not know how to describe the openning and closing of this fish net. It is
>   made up of a head-rope. Can I use "unfold" and "collect"?

The fishing net is not made up of a head rope. The head rope controls it. The net is like a giant mouth and you have answered your own question: 'open' and 'close' are better than 'unfold' or 'collect'.

So "...and the whole net will be opened or closed accordingly."

Comment: I have difficulty imagining this but the word 'gather' seems to be missing.